# Recursion to get all variants sum in array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive method that allows me to sum all the possible variants of integers in an array.

Eg. For an array with the following values [1, 2, 3, 4]

Results: [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4] etc etc..

I am totally new to recursion. What I understood was to divide the problem into a smaller one. But I can't seem  to see it for this case. Can someone help me out here?

EDIT:

```
class Stick {

    public int sum(ArrayList<Integer> array) { 
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            total += array.get(i);
        }

        return total;
    }

    public void permute(ArrayList<Integer> in, ArrayList<Integer> out) {
        if(out.size() > 0) { print(out); System.out.println(sum(out)); }

        for(int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) { 
            int item = in.get(i);
            in.remove(i);
            out.add(item);
            permute(in , out);
        }
    }

    public void print(ArrayList<Integer> integer) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < integer.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(integer.get(i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> in = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        in.add(1); in.add(2); in.add(3); in.add(4);

        Stick stick = new Stick();
        stick.permute(in, out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific here? When you say "all the possible variants", what do you mean? I am pretty sure you mean all permutations of length from 1 to the length of the input array, but I'm not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
static ArrayList<int[]> permutations(int[] a) {
    ArrayList<int[]> ret = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    permutation(a, 0, ret);
    return ret;
}

public static void permutation(int[] arr, int pos, ArrayList<int[]> list) {
    if (arr.length - pos == 1) {
        list.add(arr.clone());
    } else {
        for (int i = pos; i < arr.length; i++) {
            swap(arr, pos, i);
            permutation(arr, pos + 1, list);
            swap(arr, pos, i);
        }
    }
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int pos1, int pos2) {
    int h = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = h;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for(int i[] : IntRecursion.permutations(x)) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
    }

}
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive approach that works:

1. Write a recursive routine `permute` that takes two arrays:  `arrayIn` and `arrayOut`.  `arrayIn` contains the values that haven't been used yet, and `arrayOut` contains the partially formed result.
2. The program will be called with `arrayIn` containing the full array of values, and `arrayOut` will start as empty.
3. At each step, you will build up `arrayOut` by taking values from `arrayIn` and append them to array out.  This is the smaller case you are looking for.  The `arrayIn` gets smaller in each step until you get to the *base case* where the `arrayIn` is empty.

   Here is the solution in *Ruby*.  I've tried to make it readable if you're not familiar with *Ruby* syntax:

   ```
   # function to sum up the values of an array
   def sum(array)
       total = 0
       for elem in array
           total += elem
       end

       # return the total
       total
   end

   def permute(arrayIn, arrayOut)
       if arrayOut.count > 0
           # print out the array
           puts arrayOut.inspect

           # print out the total
           puts "total is #{sum(arrayOut)}"
       end

       # For each element in turn in arrayIn...
       for elem in arrayIn
           # remove element from arrayIn, add it to arrayOut, and recurse
           permute(arrayIn - [elem], arrayOut + [elem])
       end
   end
   ```

And when we run it with array [1,2,3]:

```
    permute([1,2,3], [])
```

The output is:

```
[1]
total is 1
[1, 2]
total is 3
[1, 2, 3]
total is 6
[1, 3]
total is 4
[1, 3, 2]
total is 6
[2]
total is 2
[2, 1]
total is 3
[2, 1, 3]
total is 6
[2, 3]
total is 5
[2, 3, 1]
total is 6
[3]
total is 3
[3, 1]
total is 4
[3, 1, 2]
total is 6
[3, 2]
total is 5
[3, 2, 1]
total is 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It seems to be the one I trying to achieve.. However, when I wrote it in java.. It seems stop at the first level of iteration [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]. Could you help me take a look?

Comment: In your permute routine, you need to make a new copy of `in` and `out` each time before removing the item from that new copy and calling `permute`.